# <Phone Number /> in a <Form /> React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My form is working without the `PhoneInput` but I'm not sure if it's possible to use phone input inside a form.

I don't get error, it's like the `handleChange` function is not working for the `PhoneInput` and I can't write anything but choosing the country.

[image: Screenshot image]

```
<Container className="container-style">
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicName">
                    <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="Name" value={data.Name} onChange={handleChange} required />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicSurname">
                    <Form.Label>Surname</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="Surname" value={data.Surname} onChange={handleChange} required />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicDateOfBirth">
                    <Form.Label>Date of Birth</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="date" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="DateOfBirth" value={data.DateOfBirth} onChange={handleChange} required />
                    {errors.DateOfBirth && <p className="error">{errors.DateOfBirth}</p>}
                </Form.Group>
            </Col>

            <Col>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="Email" value={data.Email} onChange={handleChange} required />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
                    {errors.Email && <p className="error">{errors.Email}</p>}
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPhone">
                    <Form.Label>Phone Number</Form.Label>
                    <PhoneInput
                        placeholder="Enter phone number"
                        value={data.Phone}
                        name="Phone"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    {errors.Phone && <p className="error">{errors.Phone}</p>}
                </Form.Group>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
        </Button>
    </Form>
</Container>
```

I have no idea why but can't make `PhoneInput` work for this form.

This is my `handleChange` function and the hooks:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ Name: "", Surname: "", DateOfBirth: "", Email: "", Phone: "", UniversityIds:[] })
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    setData({
        ...data,
        [target.name]: target.value
    })
}
```

Comment: Try to add a console log in your `handleChange` to see the event you are getting. That way you can be sure the input is right and can have a clear picture where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens, because the `<PhoneInput>` component likely doesn't use `event` as its first parameter in the `onChange` callback.

Try this instead:

```
<PhoneInput
    onChange={(value, data, event) => handleChange(event)}
```